# air for android disable / DEACTIVATE external keys

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

Hoping this question aids those who search google as well.

Looking to disable all external keys, such as back and home buttons on android devices as well as all the keys using internal or external keybord. I want to create a pattern of buttons they have to press to exit the app because I am creating a KIDS game and I don't want the one year old to be able to press keys to close the app but just play with the buttons and sounds on app.

Is there a way to disable all external buttons?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an air programmer, but this still answers your question.

The Android system does *not* let you disable or temporarily deactivate the home key. You can control the back key and the volume buttons, as long as your app is in the foreground. However, unless you are the launcher, you can *never* control the home key.

So in short, no you can't disable all the external buttons.

Comment: And you should not. I readily admit that there are moderately legit uses (as described in this question), but opening this up to all applications is a _terrible_ idea.

Answer (score 0):

How about deactivating all, but the home key?